# Spring Security 3.2 with Spring MVC 4.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-security

I am having some issues configuring my spring web application using gradle.
Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
            details.useVersion '4.0.1.RELEASE'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    provided
}
sourceSets {
    main { compileClasspath += configurations.provided }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    provided 'javax:javaee-web-api:7.0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:2.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.4.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.7.Final'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.26'
    compile 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp:1.4_3'
}
```

I have SecurityConfiguration.java class contains:

```
package asd;

import asd.UserDetailsServiceAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestDataValueProcessor;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = UserDetailsServiceAdapter.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public RequestDataValueProcessor requestDataValueProcessor() {
        return new CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor();
    }

    // @formatter:off
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().and()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
    // @formatter:on

    @Autowired
    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

}
```

I am using Intellij IDEA 13 Ultimate Edition. 
When I try to compile my application I get this error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method loginPage(java.lang.String)
location: class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the problem, and changing the order of the configuration makes the compilation work OK:

```
     http
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
     .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
     .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Also see the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html) of `HttpSecurity`, it has lots of examples.

Comment: When I go super class implementation of configure method, it seems have an error like mine. and() not extra.

Comment: Compile error has gone. But it says 'This webpage has a redirect loop' in browser. I can't understand that; i look a lot of examples for spring security e.g. http://spring.io/blog/2014/01/21/webinar-replay-spring-security-3-2 by Rob Winch, but I get same error in this example on my environment.

Comment: Try adding permitAll() to formLogin(),that usually happens when the login page itself is protected, I have updated my post

Comment: Thanks for your helps guys. This is solved my issue. But I don't understand why have difference between examples with same version. anyway..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change it to more appropriate like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**"); // Ignore static resources
}

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/loginfailed").permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
}
```

Comment: Same issue continues.

Comment: This is compile time error. I think it caused by library dependency, but I can't figure out why.